# wp_enqueue_script dos'nt works

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I try to loading the .js files to my page by use wp_enqueue_script in functions.php file.
Its loading the .css files but not the .js

```
function s_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 's-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    wp_enqueue_style( 's-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/styles/main-rtl.min.css');

    wp_enqueue_style( 's-tmp_styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/styles/tmpstyle.css');

    wp_enqueue_script( 's-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array(), '20151215', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 's-skip-link-focus-fix', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array(), '20151215', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 's-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/scripts/main.min.js', array(), time(), true  );

    wp_localize_script('s-js-ajax', 'ajax', array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'current_obj' => get_queried_object()
    ));

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 's_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You enqueue your scripts in the footer, check if `wp_footer();` function exists in your theme.

Try to load scripts in header (remove `true` from last argument). It will attach script to `wp_head()`

Also check `wp_localize_script` documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/

It should start something like `wp_localize_script('s-js'`